# macOS : NSButton checkmark does not appear inside NSToolbar

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I have a NSButton inside a NSToolbarItem as a member of a NSToolbar in my mac application. Something like these:

[image]

These two checkmarks are ON but they don't appear.

If I click on any of these, they toggle (the code runs) but the checkmarks never appear.

These were working on previous versions of macOS but not anymore on mojave. Anyway I am compiling this code to 10.12.

This is the storyboard structure:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Marc T. answer does not work for me. This appears to be a macOS bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embed your checkmark button in a NSView and it will work.

Comment: not working for me. Same problem. I put the switch in any other place it shows but not on a NSToolbar. Probably one more macOS bug.

Comment: What I was suggesting is to drag a NSView in the toolbar and the NSButton (checkmark) on the view. This will definitively fixing the problem because I just tested it.

Comment: I did that. Not fixing for me. I am compiling for 10.12. Still not showing in mojave. Thanks for your effort.